# Is it possible to configure a Linux/Ubuntu computer to be network silent?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, debian, linux-networking

I'm testing a customized network device using a Ubuntu computer from which I send network packets and check the actions on the network device. I'd like to only send over the packet I want, but since Ubuntu is running a lot of services (comes with the system, or from the software I installed, like Dropbox), it sends a lot of packets irrelevant to my test, and that causes a lot of trouble to my test. Can I configure a Ubuntu (or any other releases) to be network silent that would only send packets when I ask it to so? I can start with a new installation. Thank you.

Comment: With a firewall, set OUTPUT policy to DROP, and add the permissive rules for the packets you need.

Comment: Thanks! Will definitely try this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your machine completly silent with one of following solutions:

- drop any outgoing packets from firewall
- don't configure any IP addresses on interfaces where you want it to be silent

You can make it "almost" silent with:

- stop (and disable, if you want) the services that are chatty
- remove defoult route, remove DNS entries from resolver config

However for network troubleshooting, you should get use with [pcap filters](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html). In real life, network interfaces see a lot of trafic and you should get ussed to filter things that you are interested.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try the firewall and route trick. I don't fully understand which service sends which packets, maybe easier to figure out on a new installation of OS. Will try that out later.

Comment: `ss` tool may reveal some of packets. Or, you can also tell us what packets are there, maybe someone will recognize it (e.g. Bonjoir service and so on).